# truncated output from GZIPInputStream on Android

Tags: android, gzipinputstream

I must be doing something really wrong. Running following code on Android it produces truncated file (_items_) without any exceptions or problems in the log. Running the same code with OpenJDK 7 it decompresses the file correctly.

```
try {
    final InputStream fis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/sdcard/_items"));
    try {
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard/_items_");
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int n;
            while ((n = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I've tried this with Android emulator (API 18) and on Desire HD (Android 2.3.5) with the same buggy result.

Input file (_items): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6M72P2gzYmwaHg4SzRTYnRMOVk/edit?usp=sharing

Android truncated output file (_items_): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6M72P2gzYmwMUZIZ2FEaHNZUFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see the same behavior.  Please file a bug on http://b.android.com/.

Comment: Done - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63873. Any idea for workaround?

Comment: I don't know if it helps you, but recompressing the file (gunzip then gzip) resulted in a compressed data file that was correctly handled by my device.  What did you use to compress the data?

Comment: File _items_ was obtained from Glassfish 4 REST (Jersey) HTTP Response with:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Encoding: gzip

Actually file was only created from raw body of HTTP response for debugging purpose only. My original code was InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

Comment: I've tried to use com.jcraft/jzlib/1.1.3 but it has exactly the same problem. Maybe Android uses it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is to use `GZIPInputStream` from JZlib (currently only in `concatenated_gzip_streams` branch). See https://github.com/ymnk/jzlib/issues/12 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The [AOSP bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63873) has been updated with analysis by an engineer from the Dalvik team.

Summary: the gzip stream has [multiple members](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#member-format) concatenated together, and the decompressor is expected to process them all, but Dalvik's implementation is stopping after the first.

Unless there's a way to convince the data source to compress its streams differently, you will need to find a replacement for `GZIPInputStream`.